# Loading a CSV into Bigquery using bq

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I'm trying to do something I feel like is pretty simple but can't seem to get it to work.  I created a table in Bigquery and am now trying to use the bq tool to import data in to it.  The file I'm trying to import in to the table is a CSV file that uses quotes on columns that have data that could have commas in them.

**Table:**

-ColA string 
-ColB string
-ColC string
-ColD integer

**File:**

"ColA data","ColB data","ColC data", ColD data

**Command**

bq load --quote "" --format=csv dataset.TableName c:\path\filename.csv ColA:string,ColB:string,ColC:string,ColD:integer

The error I'm getting is:
"-Error while reading data, error message:  Too many values in row starting at position: 164"

The curious thing is that position 164 happens to be the end of line 1 in the file I'm trying to import. If I delete all of the data it loads that first row, but if I put the other rows back in then it fails out again.  Is there a option to set that the file is row terminator with CR/LF?  I would think that is just the default because its a standard CSV but just a thought.

Comment: Is the 4th "column" in your filename.csv an integer?

Comment: Yes, it is an integer.  I can see my question was downgraded, I'm going to going to assume I'm not being clear enough?  Sorry, I'm new to this.  Seems like what I'm trying to do should be straight forward.  I do it in SQL Server every day.  Just trying to import a csv file in to a BigQuery table using the BigQuery command line tool.  My file is comma separated with quoted identifiers because some of my data has commas in it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test using your information worked:

```
$ cat file.csv
"ColA data","ColB data","ColC data",22

$ bq load --quote "" --format=csv test_dataset.table_import_csv file.csv
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   

$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'select * from test_dataset.table_import_csv'
Waiting on bqjob_2 ... (0s) Current status: DONE

+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+
|    cola     |    colb     |    colc     | cold |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+
| "ColA data" | "ColB data" | "ColC data" |   22 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+------+

$
```

Then I add a new comma in the first row and got the same error as you: 
"Too many values in row starting at position: 40"

To solve your issue, you need to guaranty that string columns don't include any comma character, because this is the character used to identify new columns in a CSV file.

The option to change the column delimiter is [--field_delimiter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_load), try it out:

> The character that indicates the boundary between columns in the data.
>   Both \t and tab are allowed for tab delimiters.